# How can I add a UITextField or a UITextView to a UItableViewCell and edit the content?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `tableView` with a `textField` and a `textView` in two cells. Thats it.
and I added them in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.
I can't edit the content!
Probably the touch is not passing through to the text field and the `textView`.

All the solutions are asking me to use a xib with a custom cell class.

So do I have to create two new classes for a two-row `tableView` ?

Cant I just get away by adding  these as subviews to normal cell's `contentView` ?

Secondly, If using `tableView` for that kind of layout is overkill,

What  is the alternatve where I need a `textView` below a  textArea in a rectangular border with rounded corners and a separator between them with plain `UIViews` ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to go as far as creating 2 new classes. Adding them will do just fine, maybe even keeping a reference in your controller.

Check for userInteractionEnabled on your `UITableView`, `UITableViewCell`, and your `UITextField` and `UITextView`. If you disable the user interaction for a view, every subview will have it's user interaction disabled as well. If you want to disable a row's selection, just set `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a xib to subclass UITableViewCell. In this case, adding to the content view should be fine, and a subclass would not be necessary. It does also sound like you do not need a table view. A reason you might want one is if you would ever need more of these cells, otherwise a regular view controller might be more appropriate and easier to implement.

I use Core Graphics to create rounded corners on UIView objects and even add shadow effects, but there is a bit of a learning curve.  You could start by searching the Internet for UIView rounded corners.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == 0){ 
        UITextField *customField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60.0f, 10.0f, 400.0f, 60.0f)]
        customField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        customField.delegate = self;
        customField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
        customField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
        customField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
        customField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        customField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = YES;
        customField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
        customField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        [cell addSubview:customField];

    }


    if (indexPath.row == 1){ 
        UITextView *notes = [[UITextView alloc] init];
        notes.editable = YES;
        notes.font = DEFAULT_FONT(16);
        notes.text = infoNotesStr.text;
        notes.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        notes.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        notes.delegate = self;
        CALayer *layers = notes.layer;
        layers.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
        [cell addSubview:notes];

    }

}
```